# How do you export and import Visual Studio macros?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to export some macros that I have defined and be able to import them into another clean install of Visual Studio with the same module/naming structure that I have defined.

I have some menu command customizations that execute my macros - so to work in another install of Visual Studio, it needs the same macros available.

I would like to avoid a manual step of having to create the macro manually and copy/paste my macro code.

Is this possible? It doesn't seem like 'macros' is an available option to import/export through menu *Tools* -> *Import and Export Settings*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools->Macros->Macros IDE... (or Alt+F11)

Export: Expand your macros until you find the module you want to export, right-click it, choose Export ModuleName..., select a file, and Save.

Import: Select "MyMacros" or any other, right-click it, and choose Add->Add Existing Item... Select the file you just created, and Add.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still manual in how you have to specify where you are 'importing' the existing module.

Looking for something idiot proof, as one-click and done as possible.

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible.  Probably a security thing.  Has this changed in VS 2010?

Comment: Not sure. I'll let you know in a few weeks when I move up to 2010.