# Macro to create macros?

Tags: visual-studio

Over the years, I've built up a number of macros that I like to have available in visual studio.

It's always a pain to reload them and rebind them to the keyboard when I go to a different machine/rebuild/use a VM/etc.

Someone mentioned to me once that there is a way that you can write a macro that will recreate your macros and bind them to keys automatically.  Anyone know how to do that?  Is there another way to easily export/import macros (nonsensically, VS has an "export macro" function, but no import).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to import macros.

In order to do this, open the Macros IDE (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>), right click the macro group you want to add the macro to in the project explorer (MyMacros, for instance), then choose Add > Add Existing Item... and select your exported macro.

See also: [How do you export and import Visual Studio macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813380/how-do-you-export-and-import-visual-studio-macros)